# Selenium - Cannot select drop-down

Tags: c#, selenium

Picked up on a small learning project, to find the cheapest car rental by modifying dates.

**Website:** [Costco Travel](https://www.costcotravel.ca/)

**Flow:** Select Province -> Rental Cars -> Enter Airport code, change date, times.

**Issue:** Cannot select Pick-up Time or Drop-off Time.

My code so far (works well) -

```
var rootDir = Directory.GetParent(Environment.CurrentDirectory);
var chromeDriverDir = rootDir.EnumerateDirectories("ChromeDriver", SearchOption.AllDirectories);      
if ((chromeDriverDir != null) && (chromeDriverDir.Count() == 0))
    Environment.Exit(-1);

var Driver = new ChromeDriver(chromeDriverDir.ToList()[0].FullName);
Driver.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitWait = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5);
Driver.Manage().Window.Position = new System.Drawing.Point(0, 0);
Driver.Manage().Window.Maximize();
Driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://www.costcotravel.ca/");
Driver.FindElementByXPath("//label[contains(text(), \"Ontario\")]").Click(); // Select Province
Driver.FindElementByXPath("//button[contains(text(), \"Continue\")]").Click(); // Click on Continue
Driver.FindElementByXPath("//li[@data-tab=\"rental-cars\"]/a").Click(); // Click on "Rental Cars"                    Driver.FindElementById("pickupLocationTextWidget").SendKeys("yyz");
Driver.FindElementByXPath("//li[@class=\"airport\" and @data-value=\"YYZ\"]").Click(); // Select the airport
Driver.FindElementById("pickupDateWidget").Clear();                    Driver.FindElementById("pickupDateWidget").SendKeys("01/05/2018"); // Select pick-up date
Driver.FindElementByXPath("//div[@id=\"pickup_time_widget\"]/input").Click();
```

---

Now, the issue -

- **Approach 1**

`new SelectElement(Driver.FindElementById("pickupTimeWidget")).SelectByText("11:00 AM");`

> 'element not visible: Element is not currently visible and may not be
>   manipulated

- **Approach 2**

`Driver.FindElementByXPath("//div[@id=\"pickup_time_widget\"]/div/ul/li[@data-value=\"07:30 AM\"]").Click();`

> element not visible

- **Approach 3** - knew it wouldn't work, but tried it anyway.

`new SelectElement(Driver.FindElementByXPath("//div[@id=\"pickup_time_widget\"]/div/ul/li[@data-value=\"07:30 AM\"]")).SelectByIndex(5);`

> Element should have been select but was li

---

Any help on selecting a value from pickuptime/dropofftime drop-downs is greatly appreciated! Usually, I have seen many websites implementing just the `select` tag, but this website also has `ul/li` tags, which is making it complicated. Or maybe I am over thinking. Please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are underlying `select` elements that power these dropdowns. But, they are invisible and changed whenever the values in the "ul->li" dropdowns change.

There are two general options here:

- make the `select` elements visible and use the `SelectElement` class to control the dropdowns
- let the `select` elements be invisible and instead control the "ul->li" dropdown

**The first option** would just require setting the `style` of the `select` elements to "display: block":

```
IWebElement element = Driver.FindElementById("pickupTimeWidget");

((IJavaScriptExecutor)Driver).ExecuteScript("arguments[0].style = 'display:block';", element);

new SelectElement(element).SelectByText("11:00 AM");
```

**The second option** would first require a click to open up a dropdown:

```
IWebElement dropdown = Driver.FindElementById("pickup_time_widget");
dropdown.Click();
```

Then, finding a dropdown item by value/text and clicking it:

```
IWebElement dropdownItem = dropdown.FindElementByXpath(".//li[. = '11:00 AM']"); 
dropdownItem.Click();
```

Comment: whooo! Didn't knew we could modify javascript as well. Thank you very much!!